# Null Pointer Error in catching data from intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, bundler

`MainActivity.java` is Receiving Class.

`Signup.java` is Sender class.

Having Error at receiving data from intent.

**MainActivity.java - Receiving class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    // Class Variables
        private String name;
        private String email;
        private String img_url ;

        // Controls
        private TextView Email;
        private TextView Name;
        private ImageView prof_Pic;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profile_Name);
            Email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profile_Email);
            prof_Pic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_Picture);

            //Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            //extras.getExtras()
            //getIntent().getExtras();
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            Bundle extra = intent.getBundleExtra("gProfileRecord");
            if (extra != null) {
                String email= extra.getString("email");
                Email.setText(email);  **/* *** ERROR *** */**
                String name = extra.getString("firstName");
                Name.setText(name);
                String img_url = extra.getString("profile_Pic");
                Glide.with(this).load(img_url).into(prof_Pic);
            }}
```

**SignUp.java - Sender Class**

```
 public class Signup extends AppCompatActivity
                implements View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
        {
            // Variables for controls
            private LinearLayout prof_layout;
            private Button SignOut;
            private TextView Name, Email, GivenName, FamilyName, PersonId;
            private ImageView prof_pic;

            // Some class variables
            private String name;
            private String email;
            private String personGivenName;
            private String personFamilyName;
            private String personId;
            private String img_url ;
            // variables for Google SignIN process

            private SignInButton SignIn;
            private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
            private static final int REQ_CODE = 9001;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

                prof_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.profile_layout);
                SignOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bn_logout);
                SignIn = (SignInButton)findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
                Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
                Email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
                GivenName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.given_Name);
                FamilyName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.family_name);
                PersonId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.person_id);
                prof_pic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_Pic);

                // Event Listener
                SignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
                SignOut.setOnClickListener(this);
                prof_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                        .requestEmail()
                        .build();
                mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                        .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                        .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                        .build();

            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                switch(v.getId()){
                    case R.id.sign_in_button:
                        signIn();
                        break;
                    case R.id.bn_logout:
                        signOut();
                        break;
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

            }


            // Needed Methods
            private void signIn(){
                Intent intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE);
            }

            private void signOut() {
                Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                        updateUI(false);
                    }
                });
            }

            private void handleResult(GoogleSignInResult result){
                if(result.isSuccess()){
                    GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                    if (account != null) {
                        // getting the data
                    // name = account.getDisplayName();
                     email = account.getEmail();
                     personGivenName = account.getGivenName();
                     personFamilyName = account.getFamilyName();
                    // personId = account.getId();
                     img_url = account.getPhotoUrl().toString();

                        // setting the data
                       /* Name.setText(name);
                        Email.setText(email);
                        GivenName.setText(personGivenName);
                        FamilyName.setText(personFamilyName);
                        PersonId.setText(personId);
                        Glide.with(this).load(img_url).into(prof_pic);*/
                        updateUI(true);
                    }

                }else{
                    updateUI(false);
                }
            }

            private void updateUI(boolean isLogin){
                if(isLogin){
                    prof_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    SignIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Success !",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                        extras.putString("email",email);
                        extras.putString("firstName",personGivenName);
                       // extras.putString("lastName",personFamilyName);
                        extras.putString("profile_Pic",img_url);
                    intent.putExtra("gProfileRecord",extras);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Failed !",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    SignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    prof_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected  void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);

                if(requestCode == REQ_CODE){
                    GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
                    handleResult(result);
                }
            }
        }
```

> Error
>
> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                                     Process: com.example.yash.lifecatalog_beatprocrastination, PID: 12006
>                                                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.yash.lifecatalog_beatprocrastination/com.example.yash.lifecatalog_beatprocrastination.MainActivity}: **java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference**
>                                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
>                                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
>                                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>                                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
>                                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>                                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>                                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
>                                                                                                      **Caused by:** **java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                                         at com.example.yash.lifecatalog_beatprocrastination.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)**
>                                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
>                                                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
>                                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
>                                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
>                                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>                                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
>                                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
>                                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>                                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
>                                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
>                                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Answer (score 3):

you should use  `startActivityForResult(intent);` for getting data back to `onActivityResult`

Comment: Worked like a charm !

Comment: Most Welcome :)

Comment: accept it as an answer bruh

Comment: Yes accept the answer it will help others if they face the same issue :)

Comment: still data is null.

i have created **onActivityResult ** above oncreate Method for MainACtivity class.

Comment: if still data is null you need to debug and check GoogleSignInResult  result weather you are getting result or not.

Comment: I checked ! 
I am able to get result on single activity(Sender Activity) - I can display result, but not after i sent the data to another Activity - at receiving end.

What are my other options ?

Thank You !

Answer (score 1):

Stacktrace is telling you *Email* reference is null (you can easily debug and output this value to verify it). I'm guessing something is wrong in your xml layout(s), for instance make sure you're not using the same ids in _activity_main_ and _activity_signup_ .